# SQL Group By and then map out if values exists

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose I have a table called `Abilities` that look something along the lines of

| DayOfWeek | Action | Strength |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Sunday | Walk | Weak |
| Sunday | Walk | Strong |
| Sunday | Run | Strong |
| Monday | Walk | Strong |

I want to be able to do a group by the `Action` and `Strength`, and then check if the entry exists for each day of the week:

| Action | Strength | Sunday | Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday | Saturday |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Walk | Weak | Y | N | N | N | N | N | N |
| Walk | Strong | Y | Y | N | N | N | N | N |
| Run | Strong | Y | N | N | N | N | N | N |

I heard a Pivot might accomplish this, but I was wondering if there were any options available? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I heard a Pivot might accomplish this, but I was wondering if there
> were any options available?

You would be able to do this like below :

```
SELECT 
  Action,
  Strength,
  MAX(CASE WHEN DayOfWeek = 'Sunday' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END) AS Sunday,
  MAX(CASE WHEN DayOfWeek = 'Monday' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END) AS Monday,
  MAX(CASE WHEN DayOfWeek = 'Tuesday' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END) AS Tuesday,
  MAX(CASE WHEN DayOfWeek = 'Wednesday' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END) AS Wednesday,
  MAX(CASE WHEN DayOfWeek = 'Thursday' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END) AS Thursday,
  MAX(CASE WHEN DayOfWeek = 'Friday' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END) AS Friday,
  MAX(CASE WHEN DayOfWeek = 'Saturday' THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END) AS Saturday
FROM Abilities
GROUP BY Action, Strength;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #TempTable;

CREATE TABLE #TempTable
(
    [DayOfWeek] VARCHAR(10),
    [Action] VARCHAR(10),
    Strength VARCHAR(10)
)

INSERT INTO #TempTable ([DayOfWeek], [Action], Strength)
VALUES ('Sunday', 'Walk', 'Weak'),
       ('Sunday', 'Walk', 'Strong'),
       ('Sunday', 'Run', 'Strong'),
       ('Monday', 'Walk', 'Strong')

SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT [DayOfWeek], [Action], Strength, 'Y' as [value]
    FROM #TempTable
) DS
PIVOT
(
    MAX([value]) FOR [DayOfWeek] IN ([Sunday], [Monday], [Tuesday], [Wednesday], [Thursday], [Friday], [Saturday])
) PVT
```

[image]

Comment: Pivot was a solution I was thinking of trying, but was wondering if there were other solutions. Thanks a lot for this.

Answer (score -1):

```
    --CREATE TABLE         
        CREATE TABLE TEMP AS 
         (SELECT 'Sunday' AS DAYOFWEEK, 'Walk' AS ACTION, 'Weak' AS STRENGTH
            FROM DUAL
          UNION ALL
          SELECT 'Sunday', 'Walk', 'Strong'
            FROM DUAL
          UNION ALL
          SELECT 'Sunday', 'Run', 'Strong'
            FROM DUAL
          UNION ALL
          SELECT 'Monday', 'Walk', 'Strong'
            FROM DUAL);
            
        
    --SQL
    SELECT ACTION,
           STRENGTH,
           NVL("'Monday'", 'N') AS "Monday",
           NVL("'Sunday'", 'N') AS "Sunday",
           NVL("'XX'", 'N') AS "XX"
      FROM (select *
              FROM (SELECT DAYOFWEEK, ACTION, STRENGTH, 'Y' AS Y FROM TEMP)
            PIVOT(MAX(Y)
               FOR DAYOFWEEK IN('Monday', 'Sunday', 'XX')))

-- result is like this 
    
ACTION STRENGTH Monday Sunday XX
------ -------- ------ ------ --
Run    Strong   N      Y      N
Walk   Strong   Y      Y      N
Walk   Weak     N      Y      N
```

written in ORACLE PL/SQL.
However,Using "CASE WHEN" &"GROUP BY "is much easier to understand,in my opinion.

Comment: Not super-helpful since the question is for sql server.